# Агрегация - доступ к членам класса

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, доступ

Имеет ли при агрегации класс доступ к `protected`-полям другого, агрегированного класса?

```
class Date {
protected:  
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
};

class Application  {

    Date* date;
    string FinalPoint;
    int destination;

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Date {
    friend class Application;
protected:  
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
};
```

Так класс `Application` получит доступ ко всем полям объекта класса `Data`. **Любого** объекта, не только агрегированного...

Comment: Спасибо Harry:)))) сработало))

Comment: Куда ж оно денется-то... :)

Answer (score 3):

Нет. Прямой доступ к protected полям возможен только через наследование. (Если не рассматривать "друзей"  и т.п.)

Comment: Я добавила в вопрос пример кода. Компилятор выдает ошибку потому что поля Date Закрыты. реально ли как то сделать так что бы Application получил доступ к Date?

Comment: @Maryna Said: Нереально, если только вы не сделаете `Application` "другом" `Date`.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как классы сделать друзьями?